# I reverse the source code, you reverse the source code!

Tags: code-golf, quine, source-transformation

Write a program that outputs its source code in reverse when run, and outputs its source forwards when I reverse the source. If your program is "abcd", when run with no arguments it should output "dcba", and when I run the program "dcba" it should output "abcd."

This is a [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) challenge, so both your forwards and reverse program must follow the rules of proper quines. Your source code may not be a palindrome.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)  challenge, so the shortest code by byte count wins.

Answer (score 2):

## ><> (fish), 15 bytes

```
"0:g}!|o|!}g:0'
```

Reversed:

```
'0:g}!|o|!}g:0"
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiXCIwOmd9IXxvfCF9ZzowJyIsImlucHV0IjoiIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIiwiaW5wdXRfZm9ybWF0IjoiY2hhcnMifQ==)

[ti yrT](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiJzA6Z30hfG98IX1nOjBcIiIsImlucHV0IjoiIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIiwiaW5wdXRfZm9ybWF0IjoiY2hhcnMifQ==)

Comment: Could you add a try it link for the reversed version?